# Under ISPConfig 3 no account can login since resetting my MySQL root password

Tags: centos, mysql, web-hosting

I am running ISPConfig 3 under CentOS and I had to manually reset my MySQL root account password yesterday. Since resetting the password I haven't been able to login to ISPConfig's web interface with any account including my admin one.

If I try to login with username: admin and my password I get `Error
Username or Password wrong`.

I reset my MySQL root password.

```
mysqladmin -u root -p'oldpass' password 'roottest'
```

I logged into MySQL and reset admin password to test.

```
mysql -u root -p'roottest'
mysql> use dbispconfig;
mysql> database changed
mysql> update sys_user set passwort = md5('admintest') WHERE username = 'admin';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.07 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

I changed my mysql_clientdb.conf to the new password.

```
vi /usr/local/ispconfig/server/lib/mysql_clientdb.conf
<?php
$clientdb_host                  = 'localhost';
$clientdb_user                  = 'root';
$clientdb_password              = 'roottest';
?>
```

I couldn't find a way to restart ISPConfig 3, or if it's even possible.

The same error from the ISPConfig login page still shows up when trying to login with u: admin p: admintest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think the root MySQL password had anything to do with my issues.
To solve this I found my current ispconfig mysql account password here.

```
vi /usr/local/ispconfig/server/lib/config.inc.php

...
$conf['db_password'] = 'VERYLONGPASSWORDSTRING';
...
```

I then reset the MySQL ispconfig account password.

```
mysql -u root -p
mysql> use mysql
mysql> update User set Password = PASSWORD('VERYLONGPASSWORDSTRING') WHERE User = 'ispconfig';
```

I could then correctly get through the ISPConfig login page.

Comment: Had the same issue today, your solution worked like a charm!